# How to get (just) color data from my model in blender to an image for later editing?

Tags: uv, baking, color

I'm having a little problem here. I've made a model with a pretty complicated node (procedural) setup and some PBR shaders.
Now, I want to get just the color data from my model to an image so I cam make modifications later. I want to use that color in a simple setup with only diffuse and glossy shaders. I don't want to bake shadows and light, only the color.
I know my workflow is somewhat impractical, but it would really make my life easier if I 'll get an answer.

Comment: Are you using cycles?

Comment: Yeah of course.

Comment: Probably to bake Diffuse Color (choose in Bake options Diffuse and deselect everything but Color) into image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, I found out. Its actually very simple. Just bake the texture with this settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now I m not relly sure, but maybe it would be cleaner and better to do it like this (you only get the color data, when on my previous answer there was some lighting data too).

[image]

It is really bothering me that I actually don't know. It s not like, what works, more like what is strictly right. I would be very happy if someone could clear this up for me and maybe someone else too.